# How to create database link dynamically

Tags: oracle11g

I am new in oracle db...
I need to create a database link by passing link name and connection string as variable.

```
DECLARE DBLINK_NAME varchar(100) :='newdblink';
Connection varchar(250) := '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=host.name.com)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=host)))';
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE DATABASE LINK' ||DBLINK_NAME||
'CONNECT TO SCHEMA_NAME IDENTIFIED BY password USING '||Connection;
END;
```

Can any one tell me what wrong in passing this variable value in execute statement?
I am doing using TOAD and oracle 11g.

Comment: It always helps to include the error you get. You're just missing a space after the word LINK, and one before the word `CONNECT`. So it becomes `'CREATE DATABASE LINK ' ||DBLINK_NAME||
' CONNECT ...`. (Why you would want or need to create a link dynamically or on the fly is another matter - creating any object at run time usually means you're doing something wrong...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the spaces around the database link name, so your command ends up as:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINKnewdblinkCONNECT TO ...
```

which will generate an `ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed` error. You need to include a space after `LINK` and before `CONNECT`.

Your connect string also needs to be enclosed in single quotes, so you need to concatenate those as well, and they need to be escaped:

```
DECLARE
  DBLINK_NAME varchar(100) :='newdblink';
  Connection varchar(250) := '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=host.name.com)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=host)))';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE DATABASE LINK ' || DBLINK_NAME
    || ' CONNECT TO SCHEMA_NAME IDENTIFIED BY password USING '''
    || Connection || '''';
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

It's helpful to use `dbms_output` to display exactly what the `execute immediate` will try to run. You can often spot mistakes quickly - the missing spaces would have been pretty obvious - and can copy-and-patse the generated statement to run it as plain SQL, which can sometimes make other issues more obvious.

I'm not sure what the benefit of using PL/SQL, variables and dynamic SQL is here. You can just do a simple SQL statement using those values. Perhaps you intend to turn this into a procedure. But creating a link at run-time would be unusual.